# integrar bootstrap 4 a wordpress

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theme

Estoy creando mi primer tema en wordpress, y quisiera integrar bootstrap 4 al mismo, sin embargo wordpress contiene la versión 1.2 de jquery mas bootstrap la 3.3.1 de jQuery  como podria integrarlo.

```
if(!function_exists('mawt_scripts')) :
// función para cargar los script
function mawt_scripts(){
// agraga los estilos de las fuentes
wp_register_style('google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Raleway:400,700',array(),'1.0.0','all');
// agregar los estilos de Style.css con get_stylesheet_uri()
wp_register_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('google- 
fonts'), '1.0.0', 'all');  
// llamamos los estilos cargados previamente
wp_enqueue_style('style');
wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts');
// para los .js no nay un metodo de cargar para eso usamos 
get_template_directory_uri que nos devuelve la dirección de tema
wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/script.js', array('jquery'),'1.0.0', true);

// llamamos los script cargados previamente
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
 }
endif;

// llamamos a la función que contiene la carga de los archivos
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mawt_scripts');
```

este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora en mi functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Esta sería la mejor manera de llamar a tus archivos

```
add_action( 'wp_register_script', 'wp_register_script' );

//llamando a mis archivos JS

function script_init_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/tuversionjqueryfavorita.min.js');
    wp_register_script('bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array (jquery));
    wp_register_script('mi_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscriptpersonalizado.js', array (jquery));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs');
    wp_enqueue_script('mi_script');
}


add_action('init', 'script_init_method');

//llamando a mis archivos CSS

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_load_css_files' );
function prefix_load_css_files() {
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'googlefonts','https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,400i,500,700' );
    wp_register_style( 'theme-css', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('bootstrap'));
    wp_enqueue_style('theme-css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'googlefonts');
}
```